# How do I turn on terminal output in CentOS 6.8?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, apache-httpd

When I run the command

```
service httpd restart
```

the service restarts but there is no feedback to tell me that the server restarted successfully. Previous servers output a response like

```
shutting down OK
starting OK
```

How do I turn on the terminal output? I tried the following:

```
systemctl status httpd.service
journalctl -xn
journalctl -u httpd.service (-f)
```

These resulted in "command not found." When I run this command:

```
bash -x /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

I get this:

```
> + ulimit -n 1024
> + ulimit -n 4096
> + ulimit -n 8192
> + ulimit -n 16384
> + ARGV=restart
> + HTTPD=/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd
> + test -f /usr/local/apache/bin/envvars
> + . /usr/local/apache/bin/envvars
> ++ test x '!=' x
> ++ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/apache/lib
> ++ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
> + LYNX='lynx -dump'
> ++ grep apache_port= /var/cpanel/cpanel.config
> ++ sed -e 's/.*=\([.0-9]*:\)\{0,1\}//;' -e 's/[^0-9]*//g'
> + PORT=80
> + STATUSURL=http://localhost:80/whm-server-status
> ++ ulimit -H -n
> + ULIMIT_MAX_FILES='ulimit -S -n 16384'
> + '[' 'xulimit -S -n 16384' '!=' x ']'
> + ulimit -S -n 16384
> + ERROR=0
> + '[' xrestart = x ']'
> + case $ARGV in
> + /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k restart -DSSL
> + ERROR=0
> + exit 0
```

Here's the httpd script:

```
ulimit -n 1024
uulimit -n 4096
ulimit -n 8192
ulimit -n 16384
ARGV="$@"
HTTPD=/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd
if test -f /usr/local/apache/bin/envvars; then
  . /usr/local/apache/bin/envvars
fi
LYNX="lynx -dump"
PORT="$(grep 'apache_port=' /var/cpanel/cpanel.config 2>/dev/null | sed -e 's/.*=\([.0-9]*:\)\{0,1\}//;' -e 's/[^0-9]*//g' 2>/dev/null)"
STATUSURL=http://localhost:${PORT:-80}/whm-server-status
ULIMIT_MAX_FILES="ulimit -S -n `ulimit -H -n`"
if [ "x$ULIMIT_MAX_FILES" != "x" ] ; then
    $ULIMIT_MAX_FILES
fi
ERROR=0
if [ "x$ARGV" = "x" ] ; then
    ARGV="-h"
fi
case $ARGV in
start|stop|restart|graceful|graceful-stop)
    $HTTPD -k $ARGV –DSSL
    ERROR=$?
    ;;
startssl|sslstart|start-SSL)
    # echo The startssl option is no longer supported.
    $HTTPD -k start –DSSL
    ERROR=$?
    ;;
configtest)
    $HTTPD –t
    ERROR=$?
    ;;
status)
    $LYNX $STATUSURL | awk ' /process$/ { print; exit } { print } '
    ;;
fullstatus)
    $LYNX $STATUSURL
    ;;
*)
    $HTTPD $ARGV
    ERROR=$?
esac
exit $ERROR
```

Comment: No, that's not my problem. The command is running and Apache is restarting. I'm just not getting confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 6 is *pre* `systemd`; the commands you are running would be for CentOS 7 or Debian Jessie or ther systemd based services.

For CentOS 6 the `service` command should be used:

```
% sudo service httpd status
httpd (pid  2164) is running...

% ps -p 2164
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2164 ?        00:00:06 httpd
```

Comment: The service command was what I originally entered and received no response from the server. I typed "service httpd restart" but got not response. I'll clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

`service httpd restart` actually runs /etc/init.d/httpd restart. A `bash -x /etc/init.d/httpd restart` will run the script in debug mode. Using the debug mode, can you determine if the echo statements in the script actually render output? Also, at some point, the function `success` is called. This function is declared in /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions and produces the green OK text between brackets you're referring to.

On a side note, do other scripts in /etc/init.d produce output? Or only httpd?

Comment: See above for the results of the bash command you suggested -- too long for me to post it in a comment. What echo statements are you referring to? I haven't tried any other scripts.

Comment: That is not the stock CentOS httpd init script. It doesn't contain any echo statements, so I'm not surprised that you don't get output. Is it possible that you have cPanel installed or other software that tampers with the Apache init script? Please run a `rpm -qa | grep httpd` to let us see which version of Apache you have running.

Comment: Is there something I can change in httpd.conf or something to induce the echo statements?

Comment: No, httpd.conf only configures Apache and doesn't control the init script. You could add echo statements to the `/etc/init.d/httpd` script though. Please post your `/etc/init.d/httpd` script and I will let you know where to add the echo statements.

Comment: I have appended the httpd script to the original post.

Comment: OK. You would typically add a descriptive comment after every case statement, for example, after `start|stop|restart|graceful|graceful-stop)`, `startssl|sslstart|start-SSL)`, `configtest)` and `*)` you would add something like `echo "Running httpd $ARGV..."`. Each case statement saves the exit code in $ERROR. At the end of the script, $ERROR is evaluated. Just after `esac`, add the statement:
`if [ $ERROR -eq 0 ]; then echo "[ OK ]"; else echo "[ ERROR ]"; fi`